# Dispatch after last dispatch chain finishes

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

What the dispatch order should look like:

```
;; Initial Data
(dispatch [:http/get-bar])
;; We click something to update foo
(dispatch [:http/update-foo])
;; :success handler gets run:
(dispatch [:http-success/update-foo])
;; Foo data influences bar data, we want to get-bar again after foo updates
(dispatch [:http/get-bar])
```

If we have something like this:

```
{:on-click
 (fn []
   (dispatch [:http/update-foo])
   (dispatch [:http/get-bar]))}
```

The order will really look like:

```
[[:http/get-bar]
 [:http/update-foo]
 [:http/get-bar]
 [:http-success/update-foo]]
```

We are unable to guarantee the update succeeds before we get bar again.
It is possible to dispatch `:http/get-bar` as part of `:http-success/update-foo`,
but hard-coding makes things less flexible. In my specific use case, I have a
modal component that is used on two different pages. On clicking save, both
will dispatch to `[:http/update-foo]` but one page will follow up with
`[:http/get-bar]` and another will follow up with `[:http/get-baz]`,
both of which need `foo` to finish updating first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds to me like something you can solve with [re-frame-async-flow-fx](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-async-flow-fx).

Your code could look something like this:

```
(defn modal-flow [dispatch-after]
  {:first-dispatch [:http/update-foo]
   :rules [
     {:when :seen? :events :http/update-foo-success :dispatch [dispatch-after]}
   ]})

(re-frame/reg-event-fx
  :modal-1
  (fn [_ _]
    {:async (modal-flow :get/update-foo)}))

(re-frame/reg-event-fx
  :modal-2
  (fn [_ _]
    {:async (modal-flow :get/update-baz)}))
```

Async flows are really powerful for crafting these kinds of dependencies, allowing you to keep your individual handlers free from hardcoded (or awkwardly parameterized) *dispatch-after* values.